# F# threads object disposed exception

Tags: f#

Hi i have problem how to draw on panel in game loop in f#
I am getting all time exceptions when i close application.

```
let rec gameLoop (gamePanel:Panel) =  async {
        lock gamePanel ( fun() -> 
          let graphics = gamePanel.CreateGraphics(); //<-exception
          let rectangle = new System.Drawing.Rectangle(100, 100, 200, 200);
          graphics.DrawEllipse(System.Drawing.Pens.Black, rectangle);
        ) 
        return! gameLoop (gamePanel:Panel)
        }

    let startGame (p:Panel) (p1:Panel) = hide p; Async.StartAsTask(gameLoop p1);()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably disposing of the `gamePanel` in another thread so this infinite loop stops working. You need to provide a way to signal to this loop that it should exit too.

I don't think `Panel` has an `IsDisposed` method, so you should probably wrap up the `Panel` in some kind of game state object of your own where you keep track of whether the game has finished. A good way to do this would be to store a `Panel option` type in your object: if the value is `None` then the game has ended, if it is `Some panel` then the panel is still valid and can be used.

Comment: One might consider passing a CancellationToken to Async.StartAsTask and using the token to stop the game loop; see also CancellationTokenSource. 
`static member StartAsTask : Async<'T> * ?TaskCreationOptions * ?CancellationToken -> Task<'T>`